How to prevent android 14 from killing processes despite available resources?
Android 14 keeps killing processes even when there are plenty of resources available, including RAM, CPU, and battery. I’ve tried increasing the number of phantom and cached processes, disabling kill_bg_restricted_cached_idle and settings_enable_monitor_phantom_procs, disabling all battery optimisation settings, but none of these have worked.
Here’s the log of killing of browser tabs:
11-25 11:57:36.882  1284  1811 I ActivityManager: Killing 30746:com.brave.browser:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:13/u0a298i-8938 (adj 915, setSvc -10000): excessive cpu 9630 during 300034 dur=1785846 limit=2
11-25 11:57:37.028  1284  4312 I ActivityManager: appDiedLocked: app=ProcessRecord{c2c5c79 30746:com.brave.browser:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:13/u0a298i-8938} thread=android.os.BinderProxy@c4c8e24 fromBinderDied=true isKilledByAm=true reason=null
11-25 16:56:58.558  1284  4224 I ActivityManager: Killing 29568:com.brave.browser:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:29/u0a298i-8922 (adj 0, setSvc -10000): isolated not needed
11-25 16:56:58.575  1284  4224 I ActivityManager: appDiedLocked: app=ProcessRecord{479e72b 29568:com.brave.browser:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:29/u0a298i-8922} thread=android.os.BinderProxy@7ec34bd fromBinderDied=true isKilledByAm=true reason=null
11-25 17:01:36.003  1284 10196 I ActivityManager: Killing 30142:com.brave.browser:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:32/u0a298i-8919 (adj 0, setSvc -10000): isolated not needed
11-25 17:01:36.050  1284 10196 I ActivityManager: appDiedLocked: app=ProcessRecord{f476c5b 30142:com.brave.browser:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:32/u0a298i-8919} thread=android.os.BinderProxy@a822268 fromBinderDied=true isKilledByAm=true reason=null
11-25 17:01:46.668  1284  4225 I ActivityManager: Killing 30373:com.brave.browser:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:33/u0a298i-8918 (adj 0, setSvc -10000): isolated not needed
11-25 17:01:46.705  1284 10196 I ActivityManager: appDiedLocked: app=ProcessRecord{dc3ebb2 30373:com.brave.browser:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:33/u0a298i-8918} thread=android.os.BinderProxy@494614b fromBinderDied=true isKilledByAm=true reason=null
11-25 17:01:54.338  1284 12260 I ActivityManager: Killing 30411:com.brave.browser:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:34/u0a298i-8917 (adj 0, setSvc -10000): isolated not needed
11-25 17:01:54.378  1284 12260 I ActivityManager: appDiedLocked: app=ProcessRecord{f63b7d 30411:com.brave.browser:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:34/u0a298i-8917} thread=android.os.BinderProxy@23b32c9 fromBinderDied=true isKilledByAm=true reason=null
11-25 17:02:32.646  1284 12260 I ActivityManager: Killing 30444:com.brave.browser:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:35/u0a298i-8916 (adj 0, setSvc -10000): isolated not needed
11-25 17:02:32.681  1284 12260 I ActivityManager: appDiedLocked: app=ProcessRecord{bb1d10b 30444:com.brave.browser:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:35/u0a298i-8916} thread=android.os.BinderProxy@6dfdf54 fromBinderDied=true isKilledByAm=true reason=null
11-25 17:10:10.668  1284  9027 I ActivityManager: Killing 30014:com.brave.browser:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:30/u0a298i-8921 (adj 0, setSvc -10000): isolated not needed
11-25 17:10:10.699  1284  7789 I ActivityManager: appDiedLocked: app=ProcessRecord{6c536c0 30014:com.brave.browser:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:30/u0a298i-8921} thread=android.os.BinderProxy@b10c037 fromBinderDied=true isKilledByAm=true reason=null
11-25 17:10:10.735  1284  7789 I ActivityManager: Killing 28791:com.brave.browser:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:7/u0a298i-8944 (adj 0, setSvc -10000): isolated not needed
11-25 17:10:10.776  1284  7789 I ActivityManager: appDiedLocked: app=ProcessRecord{b48b4d3 28791:com.brave.browser:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:7/u0a298i-8944} thread=android.os.BinderProxy@cb5f90e fromBinderDied=true isKilledByAm=true reason=null

What else can I do to stop Android killing my processes?

What are you trying to do?  Is this about application development?

I'm just trying to use my phone. When I open an app, I expect it to run without being killed by the system. Nothing to do with development

App killing algorithms are often modified by the phone manufacturer. What phone do you use (manufacturer and model)?

General resource: Don't kill my app!

"When a service is unbound from all clients, the Android system destroys it". You cannot prevent it. None of the instances you have shown from the log are due to OOM (out of memory). Android doesn't kill apps when you are using them. Even after being closed, they are kept in cached state. If an app needs to do something actively when you are not interacting with it, it should run a Service.
